# react-native: `this.state` is undefined in login function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm having trouble accessing `this.state` in functions inside my component.

Always I get "Undefined is not a object `this.state.username`, `this.state.password`" error

**SimpleForm.js**

```
import Expo from 'expo';
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import App from './App';
import RegisterForm from './register';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Image, TouchableOpacity, AsyncStorage, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { YourRestApi } from './constants/api3';

class SimpleForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { username: '', password: '', datas: '' };
    this.login = this.login.bind(this, this.state.username, this.state.password);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.login();
  }

  registerscreen = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Register');
  }


   login() {
    YourRestApi(this.state.username, this.state.password)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.success);
        this.setState({ loading: false, datas: response });
      });
    if (this.state.datas.success === true) {
      const info = this.state.datas.message;

      AsyncStorage.setItem('info', JSON.stringify(info));
      this.props.navigation.navigate('SecondScreen');
    } else {
      alert(this.state.datas.message);
    } 
  }

   render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require('./assets/img/sd.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
          <View style={styles.content}>
            <Text style={styles.logo}>Toto Prediction </Text>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>

              <TextInput
                underlineColorAndroid='transparent' style={styles.input}
                onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username })} 
                value={this.state.username} placeholder='username'
              /> 

              <TextInput
                secureTextEntry underlineColorAndroid='transparent' style={styles.input}
                onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })} 
                value={this.state.password} placeholder='password'
              /> 
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.login} style={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            this._onPressGet.bind(this)
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.registerscreen} style={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Register</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </Image>
      </View>

    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    width: null,
    justifyContent: 'center', 
  },
  content: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  logo: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 40,
    fontStyle: 'italic',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textShadowColor: '#252525',
    textShadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 2 },
    textShadowRadius: 15,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  inputContainer: {
    margin: 20,
    marginBottom: 0,
    padding: 20,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#fff',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
  },
  input: {
    fontSize: 16,
    height: 40,
    padding: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    margin: 20,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#fff',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.6)',
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
const SimpleApp = DrawerNavigator({
  Onescreen: { screen: SimpleForm },
  SecondScreen: { screen: App },
  Register: { screen: RegisterForm },
});
Expo.registerRootComponent(SimpleApp);
```

**Api3.js**

```
export function YourRestApi(username1, password1) {
  fetchlogin(username1, password1);
}
function fetchlogin(username1, password1) {
  const details = {
    username: username1,
    password: password1,
  };
  const formBody = Object.keys(details).map(key => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(details[key])}`).join('&');

  fetch('https://*********************', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: formBody,
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('requestAppInstallation success ', response);
      return response;
    })
    .done();
}
```

I tried binding login to this.state but doesnt worked

I already checked other questions but nothing is worked

Any idea what could be causing this ?

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-decorators#autobind and autobind the login method to the class

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor replace the binding statement like below

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { username: '', password: '', datas: '' };
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: ^ Better than my answer, didn't notice you were doing that weird binding in the ctor

Comment: Nope it doesn't working I got same error  YourRestApi(this.state.username, this.state.password) this.state is undefiended

Answer (score 1):

Your login function should be bound in order for it to access the correct `this` if passed to a `Touchable`.
Could be fixed by either one of these ways:

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.login.bind(this)} ...>

 OR:

 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.login()} ...>
```

Comment: what I do is to declare the function like so functionName = () => {} binds it as well

Answer (score 0):

It is basically nothing but just an error returned by firebase in case user enters wrongly formatted email. Try entering rightly formatted email id in the signup or login form and you will not get that error from firebase.

Firebase basically checks at its end whether user entered correct mail id or not while creating new user.